# Applying a weighted lexicon for sentiment analysis on a data frame

Tags: r, sentiment-analysis, weighted

Good morning everyone, I have a dataset that's similar to this one:

```
> dataset2
   num article_num paragraph_num                                         paragraph       date  X
1    1           1             1                 Buy this stock, it's on the rise. 20/12/2017 NA
2    2           1             2   People think it's going to be a waste of money. 20/12/2017 NA
3    3           1             3                        Don't listen to them, buy. 20/12/2017 NA
4    4           2             1              Things are not going well down here. 21/12/2017 NA
5    5           2             2                   I'd suggest to sell this stock. 21/12/2017 NA
6    6           2             3                 Short paragraphs, long positions. 21/12/2017 NA
7    7           2             4                       In conclusion, I need help. 21/12/2017 NA
8    8           3             1  Bad results earlier today for a wonderful stock. 23/12/2017 NA
9    9           3             2                 But it is coming back strong now. 23/12/2017 NA
10  10           4             1               Well, it's Christmas time, be good. 25/12/2017 NA
11  11           4             2           Buy this stock, you will not regret it. 25/12/2017 NA
12  12           4             3                           Oh, and thank me later. 25/12/2017 NA
13  13           5             1 Coming back stronger than ever with the new year. 02/01/2018 NA
14  14           5             2                 Sell this stock, I'm warning you. 02/01/2018 NA
15  15           5             3                Buy this one though, very bullish. 02/01/2018 NA
```

and I have a .csv file that contains words with a "sentiment weight", here's a sample:

```
> lexicon
                     keyword         sw
1                         up  0.2332850
2                      short -0.5811601
3                       down -0.4627161
4                        buy  0.2443343
5                       good  0.2396273
6                       long  0.2972727
7                       sell -0.4274253
8                       news  0.2599005
9                   emojipos  0.3257571
10                      nice  0.4140183
```

What I want to do is to apply the lexicon to sentiment analysis on the articles (or better, the paragraphs) I have... I would like to use this specific lexicon because it's field-specific, so it would be better for my project if I could use it rather than other "generic" lexicons.

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:
I actually used tidytext and it worked, I've obtained this (on the original text, not the example I've provided):

```
# A tibble: 1,891 x 6
 num article_num paragraph_num date       word         score
   <int>       <int>         <int> <fct>      <chr>        <dbl>
 1     1           1             1 01/12/2017 summary      0.284
 2     1           1             1 01/12/2017 visa         0.741
 3     1           1             1 01/12/2017 strong       0.451
 4     1           1             1 01/12/2017 network      0.375
 5     1           1             1 01/12/2017 top         -0.323
 6     1           1             1 01/12/2017 grow         0.430
 7     1           1             1 01/12/2017 pe          -0.234
 8     2           1             2 01/12/2017 visa         0.741
 9     2           1             2 01/12/2017 date         0.274
10     2           1             2 01/12/2017 appreciated  0.620
# ... with 1,881 more rows
```

how can I ask R to calculate the overall score for each paragraph_num and each article_num?

Comment: Have you investigated `tidytext`? It makes this sort of thing quite straightforward  https://www.tidytextmining.com/

Comment: I'm trying right now but I'm only able to to use the lexicons available with 'get_sentiment()', I would like to "import" my own lexicon

Comment: You just need to use an `inner_join` with whatever lexicon dataset you like.  Have a look at what `get_sentiment` produces and you'll see it is just a list of words much like your lexicon.  The `AFINN` set, in particular, has weightings for each sentiment word, like yours.

Comment: ok thank you very much, the problem was with the fact that in my lexicon the column was named Keyword instead of word, seems like it's working now, thank you again